# merge branch with subtree to develop

Tags: git, git-subtree, subtree

I added a subtree using the tutorial below to a branch in my repo:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

However now when i change from one branch back to the branch that has the subtree i get this error

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

Which contains all the files in folder with the subtree.
Also how do i merge the branch with the subtree to develop? the subtree folder disappears.

How do i solve both of these two fundamental problems??

It seems if i just checkout the the feature branch with -f:

```
git checkout -f <branchWithSubtree>
```

For the second question using the end feature button in the gitflow in sourcetree done the trick. However now when i checkout the repository it doesnt show the subtree icon on the left hand side even thought the subtree is there, doesnt anyhow know if this is a sourcetree issue, or i am not doing something right?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

After some research i realised that my issues with subtree were quite small, as posted above, checking out with '-f' solved the first issue.

The subtree icon in sourcetree answer is solved in the link below.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/276191/cannot-add-existing-subtree-to-sourcetree

Hope this helps.